# I cant find the cause of the segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a basic shell-like program in C for Linux, and I am running into some problems. I get a segmentation fault somewhere in the `parse_cmdline` function that I have created, but I expect that the argumens = parse_cmdline (cmdline); might not be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char** parse_cmdline(const char *cmdline){

    char** input;
    int counter = 0;
    char* token;
    token = strtok(cmdline);
    
    int tokenlen = strlen(token);
    
    input = realloc(input , sizeof(char*)+tokenlen*sizeof(char));
    input[counter] = token;
        
    while( token != NULL ) {
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            printf("%s\n",token);
            tokenlen = strlen(token);
            input = realloc(input , sizeof(char*)+tokenlen*sizeof(char));
            counter++;
            input[counter] = token;
    }
    return input;
}

int main(){

    char* cmdline = NULL;
    size_t cmdlength = 0 ;
    char** arguments;

    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    while (1){
    
        getline(&cmdline , &cmdlength , stdin);
        arguments = parse_cmdline(cmdline);

        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
        
            if(access(arguments[0], F_OK) == 0 ) {
            
                    if(access(arguments[0], X_OK)){
                    
                        execv(arguments[0],arguments);
                        exit(0);
                        
                    } else {
                    
                        printf("%s: Permission denied",arguments[0]);
                        exit(-1);
                    
                    }
                    
            } else {
            
                printf("%s: No such file or directory",arguments[0]);
                exit(-1);
            
            }
            
        } else {
        
            waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
            
        }
            
        free(arguments);
        cmdline = NULL ;
        cmdlength = 0 ;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I cant find the cause of the segmentation fault" -- If you run yur program in a debugger, you will know immediately. You say you use Linux. In `gdb`, `run` thr program until it crashes, then type `where`. You will get a traceback of all function calls up to the current point in the program. If you compile with `-g`, you'll get useful line numbers and file names, too.

Comment: Please note that you are passing a (single) `const char *` to [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) *"This function is destructive: it writes the '\0' characters in the elements of the string str. In particular, a string literal cannot be used as the first argument of strtok"*

Comment: void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size) attempts to resize the memory block pointed to by ptr that was previously allocated with a call to malloc or calloc. In your case you've used realloc() on uninitialised input first time you use it.

Comment: ...otherwise initiliase `char** input = NULL` which is safe to pass to `realloc`.

Comment: What does `tokenlen`, the length of each element's string, have to do with the length of the pointer array? If, say, the third token has length `2` then you will shorten that array and index out of bounds. That array length should be based on `counter`, not `tokenlen`.

Comment: ...also you'll need either a `NULL` sentinel to mark the end of the pointer array, or inform the caller of the number of elements.

Comment: In case you use gcc use `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` and fix the code so you don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues that immediately jump out to me:

1. As @Bob__ observed in comments, `strtok()` is destructive, so you should not pass a `const char *` as its first argument.  Your compiler ought at least to be warning about this.  Do not ignore your compiler's warnings, *especially* when you're bug hunting.  If you're OK with that string being modified by `parse_cmdline()` than remove the `const` from its parameter (and don't pass `const` data to the function).  If you don't want the input data modified then make a local non-`const` copy or use something other than `strtok()`.
2. `strtok()` returns `NULL` when there are no more tokens, but you use its result without first testing for that.  The null check in the `while` condition comes too late, both for the initial `strtok()` call and for the one in the loop.